# Extent Interaction event handling with Openlayers

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

For a number of events in Openlayers there are event listeners tied to the end of a specified action. E.g. with the map you can determine moveend with an event listener. What I'm trying to to do is apply an event listener to the extentInteraction to determine when the user is done modifying the extent with a shiftkeyonly condition. Here is the extent interaction initialization:

export const extent = new ExtentInteraction({
boxStyle: styles,
condition: shiftKeyOnly,
pointerStyle: [],
});

I only see an event listener for 'extentchanged':

[Extent.ExtentEvents](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Extent.ExtentEvent.html)
[Extent Interaction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Extent-Extent.html)

Here is my basic attempt:

```
    extent.on('extentchanged', (listener) => {
        console.log('extentchanged');
    });
```

The problem is that this is being fired off every time the extent changes. I only want to look at the extent values once the change is complete. Any suggestions?